# R function rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext() returns Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am executing Rstudio in Windows.  When I try to execute function rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext(), it returns "Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?"

Here is my session code:

```
library(rstudioapi)
rstudioapi::isAvailable()
rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()
```

Console output is:

```
> library(rstudioapi)
> rstudioapi::isAvailable()
[1] TRUE
> rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

Here is sessionInfo() output:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rstudioapi_0.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] rstudio_0.98.1103 tools_3.1.3
```

Does anyone see the problem and know of a solution?  Thanks!